# Is it possible to make MAUI app UI look like Windows 11 native applications?

Tags: c#, maui

I'm new to .NET MAUI, and I have a question about that: Is it possible to make the MAUI application's UI, look like Windows 11's native applications without any external tools?

I mean to make UI components' appearance look similar to Windows 11 native applications. Take a look at these.

[image: Settings]

[image: Search]

[image: Range]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use the Listview or the collectionview to create the list. You can check the [ListView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/listview?view=net-maui-7.0) and the [Collectionview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/collectionview/?view=net-maui-7.0) for more information.

In addition, the [Entry](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/entry?view=net-maui-7.0) and the [slider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/slider?view=net-maui-7.0) can also be found in the Microsoft document.

Here is the Slider sample:

```
 <Slider Maximum="360" WidthRequest="200" />
```

[image]

Here is the Entry sample:

```
<Entry Placeholder="Enter something here" WidthRequest="150"></Entry>
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Are these components working without the need of installing any other thing on the project?

Comment: You do not need to install any other thing for your project.